# Woocommerce cart hide remove button

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to hide the 'remove from cart' button from a specific product because this is a setup cost and reliable on the other products in the cart. Except the table doesn't have a unique class/ID to select the specific row of the product.

Is there a way to remove the 'remove from cart' button from a specific product?

Thanks!

Comment: I found a way around it by hiding the remove button with jQuery, but a PHP approach would be better I think